# deauthorize the user from facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth, restfb

I am getting

```
 A network error occurred while trying to communicate 
with Facebook: Facebook POST failed (HTTP status code 400)
```

when I 
try to deauthorize the user from an app.

I am using `restfb1.5.1`.  I 
set the access token and other things correctly. This is how I call .

```
DefaultFacebookClient facebookClient = new 
DefaultFacebookClient(access_token); 
boolean result = false; 
try { 
        result = facebookClient.deleteObject(userId); 
} catch (com.restfb.FacebookException e) { 

     e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Due to facebook, if I don't specify the permission,it will 
deauthorizes the app.

Anything that I miss?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: does anything else work?

Comment: Yes. I can publish even status to user wall correctly. I am using the same configuration for creating client.

Answer (score 0):

Use restfb1.6.6 and Check!!

Best wishes..

Comment: Is it possible to continue using restfb1.5.1 for delete? Because I am only allow to use that lib :(